# PowerShell error in Shell Launcher script

Tags: powershell, windows-10, enterprise

I'm trying to setup Shell Launcher on Windows 10 Enterprise latest ver.

following Microsoft's [guide here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/blob/develop/Samples/ShellLauncherV2/SampleBridgeWmiScripts/README.md).

I saved the content of [this PowerShell script](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/blob/develop/Samples/ShellLauncherV2/SampleBridgeWmiScripts/ShellLauncherBridgeWmiHelpers.ps1) in a file and ran it according to the guide, here is the error I'm receiving. any Ideas what's the problem?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il9TY.png

Answer (score 0):

Basically what happens here is your CIM server has no info about your MDM_AssignedAccesss class in given namespace. Before getting CimInstance in script (lines 1-7 from the script you provided):

```
$NameSpace = "root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap"
$Class = "MDM_AssignedAccess"

function Get-AssignedAccessCspBridgeWmi
{
    return Get-CimInstance -Namespace $NameSpace -ClassName $Class
}
```

you have to set it up, which can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-mdm-bridge

Comment: Thanks, that stopped the first error from appearing again, but that script from the MSFT Docs website itself, generated this error after i pressed enter, is this normal and expected?
https://imgur.com/a/NZmuXza